# Ansible, how to set a global fact using roles?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to deploy a small k3s cluster with just two server nodes at the moment. Deploying the first server node, which I refer to as "master" is easy to set up with Ansible. However, setting up the second server node, which I refer to as "node" is giving me a challenge because I need to pull the value of the node-token from the master and use it to call the k3s install command on the "node" vm.

I'm using Ansible roles, and this is what my playbook looks like:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  roles:
    - { role: k3sInstall , when: 'server_type is defined'}
    - { role: k3sUnInstall , when: 'server_type is defined'}
```

This is my main.yml file from the k3sInstall role directory:

```yaml
- name: Install k3s Server
  import_tasks: k3s_install_server.yml
  tags:
    - k3s_install
```

This is my k3s_install_server.yml:

```yaml
---
- name: Install k3s Cluster
  block:
    - name: Install k3s Master Server
      become: yes
      shell: "{{ k3s_master_install_cmd }}"
      when: server_role == "master"

    - name: Get Node-Token file from master server.
      become: yes
      shell: cat {{ node_token_filepath }}
      when: server_role == "master"
      register: nodetoken
    
    - name: Print Node-Token
      when: server_role == "master"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ nodetoken.stdout }}"
        # msg: "{{ k3s_node_install_cmd }}"

    - name: Set Node-Token fact
      when: server_role == "master"
      set_fact:
        nodeToken: "{{ nodetoken.stdout }}"

    - name: Print Node-Token fact
      when: server_role == "node" or server_role == "master"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ nodeToken }}"
    # - name: Install k3s Node Server
    #   become: yes
    #   shell: "{{ k3s_node_install_cmd }}{{ nodeToken }}"
    #   when: server_role == "node"
```

I've commented out the `Install k3s Node Server`task because I'm not able to properly reference the nodeToken variable that I'm setting when `server_role == master`.

This is the output of the debug:

```
TASK [k3sInstall : Print Node-Token fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": "K10cf129cfedafcb083655a1780e4be994621086f780a66d9720e77163d36147051::server:aa2837148e402f675604a56602a5bbf8"
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

My host file:

```
[p6dualstackservers]
server1 ansible_ssh_host=10.63.60.220
server2 ansible_ssh_host=10.63.60.221
```

And I have the following host_vars files assigned:

*server1.yml*:

```yaml
server_role: master
```

*server2.yml*:

```yaml
server_role: node
```

I've tried assigning the nodeToken variable inside of *k3sInstall/vars/main.yml* as well as one level up from the k3sInstall role inside *group_vars/all.yml* but that didn't help.

I tried searching for a way to use block-level variables but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the variable for *master* only it's not available to other hosts. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: master,node
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        nodeToken: K10cf129cfedaf
      when: inventory_hostname == 'master'
    - debug:
        var: nodeToken
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [master] => 
  nodeToken: K10cf129cfedaf
ok: [node] => 
  nodeToken: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

If you want to *"apply all results and facts to all the hosts in the same batch"* set [run_once: true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once). For example,

```yaml
- hosts: master,node
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        nodeToken: K10cf129cfedaf
      when: inventory_hostname == 'master'
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: nodeToken
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [master] => 
  nodeToken: K10cf129cfedaf
ok: [node] => 
  nodeToken: K10cf129cfedaf
```

---

In your case, add `run_once: true` to the task

```yaml
    - name: Set Node-Token fact
      set_fact:
        nodeToken: "{{ nodetoken.stdout }}"
      when: server_role == 'master'
      run_once: true
```

The above code works because; quoting from [run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task):

> *"Boolean that will bypass the host loop, forcing the task to attempt to execute on the first host available and afterward apply any results and facts to all active hosts in the same batch."*

Safer and more robust code would be adding a standalone *set_fact* task. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        nodeToken: "{{ nodetoken.stdout }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == 'master'
    - set_fact:
        nodeToken: "{{ hostvars['master'].nodeToken }}"
      run_once: true
```

Said that you might want to try the below code

```yaml
- block:

    - shell: "{{ k3s_master_install_cmd }}"

    - shell: "cat {{ node_token_filepath }}"
      register: nodetoken
    
    - debug:
        var: nodetoken.stdout

    - set_fact:
        nodeToken: "{{ nodetoken.stdout }}"
 
  when: server_role == 'master'
  become: true

- set_fact:
    nodeToken: "{{ hostvars['master'].nodeToken }}"
  run_once: true
  
- debug:
    var: nodeToken
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `when` in this use case is probably not the best fit, you would probably  be better [delegating some tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) to the so-called *master* server.

What you can do to define what server is the master, based on your inventory variable, is to delegate a fact to `localhost`, for example.

Then again, to get the token from your file in the *master* server, you can delegate this task and fact only to this server.

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        master_node: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: server_role == 'master'
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

    - set_fact:
        token: 12345678
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: "{{ hostvars.localhost.master_node }}"
      delegate_facts: true

    - debug:
        var: hostvars[hostvars.localhost.master_node].token
      when: server_role != 'master'
```

This yields the expected:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************
skipping: [node1]
ok: [node2 -> localhost]
skipping: [node3]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************
ok: [node1 -> node2]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
skipping: [node2]
ok: [node1] => 
  hostvars[hostvars.localhost.master_node].token: '12345678'
ok: [node3] => 
  hostvars[hostvars.localhost.master_node].token: '12345678'
```